# Automator folder action to transfer specific files to dropbox folder

Tags: folder-action

I need an Automator Folder Action workflow to transfer files to my dropbox folder.
I have a folder with many subfolders and when new files in a specific format are created, it will move them in the exact same name folder in my Dropbox folder.

For example, if I just created a new CBZ file in a specific directory, I want it to search for the same folder name in dropbox and then transfer itself in said folder.

Can someone help me to do this with Automator?
Thanks

Comment: Why not work directly on files in the Dropbox folder?

Comment: My dropbox folder is not in local. My directory is huge so i work in it then just transfer the new cbz files to Dropbox but other subdirectories with many pictures stay in it all the time.